# Polynomial discrete mathematics

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

I ran into this question:

Let $p$ be a prime number. We will work on $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Let $d$ be a divisor of $p-1$, $(p-1)/d=r$.

Show that the equation $x^{d}=1$ has exactly $d$ solutions on $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$
and they are: $1^r$, $2^r$, ..., $(p-1)^r$.

Thanks in advance,

Yaron

Answer (score 1):

hint: $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is field 
and i know  $\mathbb{Z}_{p}-\{0\}$ is group with multiplication.
hence $$\forall  x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}-\{0\}=\{\overline 1,...,\overline {p-1}\} :x^{\phi( p)}=1$$($o(a)||\mathbb{Z}_{p}-\{0\}|=\phi( p)$)
then $x^{p-1}=1$ and $x^{dr}=1$  and clearly answer is :$\{ 1^r,..., ({p-1})^r\}$

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't understand what you wrote or how i go on from that

Comment: sorry, i don't really understand your hint.

Comment: yes.
i didn't understand the -{0} part

Comment: ok. so you took Zp and did minus [0]. what did you get after that?

i mean what does the x to the power of phi mean?

Comment: in finite group we have $o(a)||g|$ and clearly $|g|={\phi( p)}$ o(a) is order of element

Comment: i should probably learn the subject more cause i dont understand the terms you are using.

thanks very much anyways.

Comment: @user76508:see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/lecture-23), for $d∣p−1,$ the polynomial $x^d−1\equiv0\pmod p$ has exactly d roots mod p.

As $\frac{p-1}r=d, (x^r)^d=x^{r\cdot d}=x^{p-1}$ which is $\equiv1\pmod p$ using Fermat's Little Theorem if $(x,p)=1$

Now, $x$ can assume $p-1$ in-cogruent values.

So, for integer $y, 1\le y\le p-1$ $y^r, (y,p)=1\implies y$ is a solution of $x^d\equiv1\pmod p$

Comment: thank you very much,
I'll try to understand and read the lecture

Comment: can you please show me how they got to equation (9) in the lecture you brought?

i couldnt really understand the algebra...

Comment: it's ok, i got it.

Thank you very much.